# How to open Phone App from within another app without calling?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios5, phone-call

I'm trying to open just the Phone app from within an application I'm making without dialing a number.

I've tried:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"tel://";
```

but it does nothing. Anyone have a correct solution. I've seen other questions on this topic but none have worked.

This worked for opening SMS app:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"sms:";
```

Just wont work for phone app.
Anyone know the solution?

Comment: Have you tried?
NSString *stringURL = @"tel:";

Comment: yes. I tried that first. does not do a thing.

Comment: Why do you want to do it? Just curious. Maybe there's another way to benefit the user.

Comment: please run your application on device as this will work on device only....

Comment: @macbirdie I'm developing an app that backs up callhistory. Then import other backups to the phone app. After an import of a backup I want the app to ask to open the Phone app to view the call history. Not call any number when it goes into phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this,

```
NSString *stringURL = @"tel:phonenumber";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringURL]];
```

Comment: this did not work. It opened phone app and dialed "phonenumber" then went back to my app after I ended call. I don't think there's a possible way to open JUST the phone app without calling.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution using swift? i.e. just tel: returns you back to the calling app.